# Magento 2 - How to make a custom category attribute of text type (string)?

Tags: magento2, category, custom-attributes, category-attribute

I have to make a custom attribute for categories of type string (text). I only saw how to make yes/no, email and other types, but there is no simple type of this attribute like string? How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember after you add attribute by install script, add ui_component to make it show on manage category section

in app/code/Mycompany/CategoryAttribute/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="myfieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">section123</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="category_code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="external_url">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">If empty, nav menu item links to category page; otherwise link to this url</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">35</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">External URL</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="image2">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Page Banner</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="catalog/category_image/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>


    </fieldset>
</form>
```

UpgradeData.php

```
<?php
/* app/code/Mycompany/CategoryAttribute/Setup/UpgradeData.php */

namespace Mycompany\CategoryAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
/**
 * Upgrade Data script
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Category setup factory
     *
     * @var CategorySetupFactory
     */
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($context->getVersion()
            && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0
        ) {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
            $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'category_code'
            );
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'category_code', [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Category Code',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 7,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                ]
            );

            $idg =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');
            $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $idg,
                'category_code',
                46
            );
            $setup->endSetup();
        }

        if ($context->getVersion()
            && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2') < 0
        ) {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
            $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'image2_url'
            );
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'image2_url', [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Image2 URL',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 8,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                ]
            );

            $idg =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');
            $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $idg,
                'image2_url',
                47
            );
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
            $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'image3_url'
            );
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'image3_url', [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Image3 URL',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 9,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                ]
            );

            $idg =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');
            $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $idg,
                'image3_url',
                48
            );
            $setup->endSetup();
        }

        if ($context->getVersion()
            && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.3') < 0
        ) {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
            $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'image2_alt'
            );
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'image2_alt', [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Image2 Alt',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 10,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                ]
            );

            $idg =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');
            $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $idg,
                'image2_alt',
                49
            );
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
            $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'image3_alt'
            );
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'image3_alt', [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'Image3 Alt',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 11,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                ]
            );

            $idg =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');
            $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $idg,
                'image3_alt',
                50
            );
            $setup->endSetup();
        }

        if ($context->getVersion()
            && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.4') < 0
        ) {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
            $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'external_url'
            );
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'external_url', [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => 'External url',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 12,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                ]
            );

            $idg =  $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');
            $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $idg,
                'external_url',
                51
            );

            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. So, can you tell me how this xml (category_form.xml) works? It only extends the existing stuff?

Comment: In magento2.1, not like magento1, after you added category attribute, it will not automatically show in backend edit category section, you have to define how to show it. In the above example, we open a new fieldset "myfieldset" and all the additional attributes will be shown in the new group "myfieldset" , that is , not alone with those default field e.g. name, description